# Where am I going wrong about this reasoning?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Consider to define a char pointer in C. Then the instruction:

```
char *str
str = "Hello World!"
```

isn't producing any error. Posing that my knowledge of C and pointer is barely acceptable, why is this instruction correct? Shouldn't it be:

```
str = &("Hello World!");
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky `"Hello world"` is a `char` array, that decays to a pointer in most contexts, but that can be distinguished from one with `sizeof`.

Comment: The lines above will definitively generate multiple errors. That's not valid C for various reasons, (Sidnote - phrases: C does not have instructions. YOu might mean statements, but the first line is not a statement either. Even if we consider you just forgot the semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [....]

Here, the string literal, which is basically of type array of `char`<sup>FootNote</sup>, while used as the RHS of the assignment operator, decays to the pointer to the first element of the array.

Thus, the LHS (a pointer type) and RHS (a derived pointer type) are compatible, as required by the assignment operator and the statement is valid.

That said,

```
 str = &("Hello World!");
```

is not valid, as `&("Hello World!");` is of type `char (*) [13]` (pointer to an array of 13 `char`s), and is not the compatible type for a `char *`, the LHS of the assignment.

---

FootNote:

Quoting `C11`, §6.4.5

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.78) The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence. [....]

Answer (score 3):

The string literal `"Hello World!"` is an anonymous object of type `char [13]`, i.e. array of 13 chars, which implicitly decays to a pointer to the first character of the array (`char *`!) in all contexts except when the array occurs as an operand to the & or in a `sizeof`/`_Alignof`.

```
str = &("Hello World!")
```

(which can be written without the parentheses `str = &"Hello World!"`) is specifically *not* correct, because the result of `&("Hello World!")` is of type `*char (*)[13]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 13 characters!

GCC would diagnose this as

```
test.c:3:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     str = &"Hello World!";
```